# Slow mongodb query, how can it happen?

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query in MongoDB:

```
db.getCollection('message').aggregate([
 {
     "$match": {
         "who" : { "$in" : ["manager", "woker"] },
         "sendTo": { "$in": ["userId:243369", "userId:160921"] },
         "exceptSendTo": { "$nin": ["userId:37355"] },
         "msgTime": { "$lt": 1559716155 },
         "isInvalid": { "$exists": false }
      }
 },
 {
     "$sort": { "msgTime": 1, "who": 1, "sendTo": 1 }
 },
 {
     "$group": { "_id": "$who", "doc": { "$first": "$type" } }
 }

], { allowDiskUse: true})
```

forget about the field meaning. and I have this index:

```
/* 1 */
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "db.message"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "who" : 1.0,
            "sendTo" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "who_sendTo",
        "ns" : "db.message"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "msgTime" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "msgTime_1",
        "ns" : "db.message"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "msgTime" : 1.0,
            "who" : 1.0,
            "sendTo" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "msgTime_1.0_who_1.0_sendTo_1.0",
        "ns" : "db.message",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

Perform the query above, It cost 1.52s, use explain to see it indeed has used msgTime_1.0_who_1.0_sendTo_1.0 index.

Why is query is still low while index has been used? and is there any way to solve the low problem like change index or something?

Comment: How many records does your collection have?. Also remember $ne or $nin will perform slower

Comment: @KannanT about 800,000 records

Comment: I dont think { "$first": "$type" } makes any sense with the sort. Could you post an example document?

Comment: {
    "name" : "system message",
    "avatar" : "",
    "sendFrom" : 0,
    "version" : "1.0",
    "type" : "news",
    "target" : "sierra://webview",
    "who" : "system",
    "extra" : {
        "type" : "cash_account",
        "url" : "https://www.test.cn/my/coin",
        "token" : 1,
        "target" : ""
    },
    "cmd" : "notify",
    "show" : {
        "title" : "pushtest",
        "subTitle" : "reward100",
        "content" : "chage：$100"
    },
    "isMassSend" : 0,
    "sendTo" : [ 
        "userId:9117"
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are using the sort at all the way you intend to use it.
The $firs argument requires a sort on the actual first arguement
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/

You need to sort the key you want the first element of. 
OR you could use $$ROOT, witch returns the first document.

I think you should modify it to something like:

```
{"$sort": {"who": 1, "msgTime": 1, "sendTo": 1}},
{"$group": {"_id": "$who", "doc": {"$first": "$$root"}}},
```

In this case the $group operator can find the result for each group "instantly" since they are all next to each other.

If you are only interested in the type, add an projection:

```
{'$project': {'doc.type': 1}
```